# minihtml is not compress output

Tags: performance

I am using the [Minify HTML](https://www.drupal.org/project/minihtml) module to compress the HTML output. Once, I enable this module and view my node page, the HTML is not compressed. Is there any additional setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

Remember what this module does is:

**This module removes all the whitespace in your HTML except those between TAGS.**

It will not compress all your HTML into one single line.

Comment: Can't be share, right now this is in development state.

Comment: @RajeshVishwakarma This should answer your question, but if it doesn't, and the module makes literally zero difference to the output of your html, and it should work according to the docs, please file a bug report on drupal.org.

Comment: Ohh!,I missed to enable checkbox on performance (admin/config/development/performance) page.